# Can ThirdParty Softwares Bypass Windows Firewall Outbound Rules During OS Startup?

Tags: windows-8.1, firewall

From what I've read online, There's a gap between TCP/IP Stack and Firewall Service start during Windows (8.1) boot, which on slow machines may last for several seconds. Is it possible for a program to take advantage of this opportunity and stablish outbound connections even if Windows Firewall is configured to block all inbound/outbound traffic? If the answer is YES, What can I do about it?
Not sure but I believe this actually happened for me and a program (*-cough-* MalwaeBytes AntiMalware) checked for updates before I log in, all while Windows Firewall was supposed to stop it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you installed Malwarebytes then you had already created an exception rule for it

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your fast comment, I knew its gonna add rules so deleted those manually. I have windows firewall controll installed and it is set to disable rules created in such senarios, so it can not be the reason.

Comment: Well, Windows starts it’s own services before anything else, so the answer to your scenarios is:  no

Comment: @Ramhound That's good news, actually it happened only once. might be a bug or something. so normally its not possible to bypass outbound rules during boot. thats all I wanted to know, if you post, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: If you are worried set any third-party service to be delayed for 30-60 seconds